# Should I put an "as" when use the word "pronounce"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I asked a [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238772/109190) just now.

> she pronounces "would need" **as** /wudnt/.

A nice answerer @Weather Vane says:"I pronounce it /.../".

So, is it unnecessary to put an "as" when use the word "pronounce"?

Comment: You don't need to use "as" after "pronounce" and also not after "consider."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As" is used in *comparisons*, so you would only need to use it if you were comparing the pronunciation to another word.

Eg:

> You should pronounce the word "would" as "wood".

However, even if there were no comparison and you were giving a pronunciation guide which is not actually another word, in *spoken* English it doesn't always feel natural to say two identically pronounced words next to each other, and I believe that many speakers would insert "as" anyway, just to break the two up and make their speech clearer.

Having said that, I don't feel your question is actually about pronunciation. "Wouldn't" is a *contraction* - not an alternative pronunciation of "would not".

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Thank you. Does pronunciation guide refer to some kind of IPA like /wudnt/?

Comment: @WXJ96163 Yes exactly that.